# Bare metal audio output on Raspberry Pi3 working in AARCH64 asm but not the C version

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi3, arm64, bare-metal

I have been trying to write a bare metal kernel for over a year now and I am up to the point where I am ready to start working on audio output. I have written the code in asm however since I'm not great at it I'm not sure how I can pass audio samples as arguments to a asm function. I tried to rewrite it in C however it isn't working. This problem is really a spot the difference. I know my asm version works but the audio sample is written into the play_audio function. My goal is to have a init function for the audio with no arguments and a play_audio function that takes the pointer to the start of the audio function and a pointer to the end of the audio file. The audio file to be played is a 16 bit unsigned int pcm file. The same file that I'm trying to use for the C audio part is used successfully in the asm version. Since I set the hardware pwm to expect 13bit audio at 41400Hz there is a shift to convert the sample from 16bit to 13 bit so this isn't a mistake.

Not_working_audio.c

```
void init_audio_jack_c()//ERROR IN HERE
{
    //Set phone jack to pwm output
    uint32_t *gpio_addr = (uint32_t *)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + GPIO_BASE);
    uint32_t *gpio_gpfsel4_addr = gpio_addr + GPIO_GPFSEL4;
    *gpio_gpfsel4_addr = GPIO_FSEL0_ALT0 | GPIO_FSEL5_ALT0;

    //Set clock
    uint32_t *clock_manager_addr = (uint32_t *)(((PERIPHERAL_BASE + CM_BASE) & 0x0000FFFF) | ((PERIPHERAL_BASE + CM_BASE) & 0xFFFF0000));
    *(clock_manager_addr + CM_PWMDIV) = (CM_PASSWORD | 0x2000);

    *(clock_manager_addr + CM_PWMCTL) = ((CM_PASSWORD | CM_ENAB) | (CM_SRC_OSCILLATOR + CM_SRC_PLLCPER));

    //Set PWM
    uint32_t *pwm_manager_addr = (uint32_t *)(((PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0x0000FFFF) | ((PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0xFFFF0000));
    *(pwm_manager_addr + PWM_RNG1) = 0x1624;
    *(pwm_manager_addr + PWM_RNG2) = 0x1624;

    *(pwm_manager_addr + PWM_CTL) = PWM_USEF2 + PWM_PWEN2 + PWM_USEF1 + PWM_PWEN1 + PWM_CLRF1;

    printf("[INFO] Audio Init Finished");
}


int32_t play_16bit_unsigned_audio(uint16_t *start, uint16_t *end)
{
    if(end < start) 
    {
        printf("[ERROR] End is less than start.");
        return 1;
    }
    if((start - end) % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Isn't a multiple of two so it isn't 16bit");
        return 2;
    }

    uint16_t *end_of_file = (uint16_t *)(uint64_t)(((uint32_t)(uintptr_t)end & 0x0000FFFF) | ((uint32_t)(uintptr_t)end & 0xFFFF0000));

    //FIFO write
    while(start != end_of_file)
    {
        uint16_t sample = start[0];
        sample >>= 3;
        *(uint32_t *)((((uint32_t)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0x0000FFFF) | ((uint32_t)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0xFFFF0000)) + PWM_FIF1) = sample;

        start++;
        sample = start[0];
        sample >>= 3;
        *(uint32_t *)((((uint32_t)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0x0000FFFF) | ((uint32_t)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0xFFFF0000)) + PWM_FIF1) = sample;

        //FIFO wait
        while(*(uint32_t *)((((uint32_t)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0x0000FFFF) | ((uint32_t)(PERIPHERAL_BASE + PWM_BASE) & 0xFFFF0000)) + PWM_STA) != PWM_FULL1);
        start++;
    }
    printf("[INFO] Completed Audio");
    return 0;
}
```

Working_audio.s

```
.section .text.init_audio_jack, "ax", %progbits
.balign 4
.globl init_audio_jack;
.type init_audio_jack, %function
init_audio_jack:
    mov w0,PERIPHERAL_BASE + GPIO_BASE
    mov w1,GPIO_FSEL0_ALT0
    orr w1,w1,GPIO_FSEL5_ALT0
    str w1,[x0,GPIO_GPFSEL4]

    // Set Clock
    mov w0, PERIPHERAL_BASE
    add w0, w0, CM_BASE
    and w0, w0, 0x0000FFFF

    mov w1, PERIPHERAL_BASE 
    add w1, w1, CM_BASE
    and w1, w1, 0xFFFF0000

    orr w0,w0,w1
    mov w1,CM_PASSWORD
    orr w1,w1,0x2000 // Bits 0..11 Fractional Part Of Divisor = 0, Bits 12..23 Integer Part Of Divisor = 2
    brk #0
    str w1,[x0,CM_PWMDIV]

    mov w1,CM_PASSWORD
    orr w1,w1,CM_ENAB
    orr w1,w1,CM_SRC_OSCILLATOR + CM_SRC_PLLCPER // Use 650MHz PLLC Clock
    str w1,[x0,CM_PWMCTL]

    // Set PWM
    mov w0, PERIPHERAL_BASE
    add w0, w0, PWM_BASE
    and w0, w0, 0x0000FFFF

    mov w1,PERIPHERAL_BASE
    add w1, w1, PWM_BASE
    and w1, w1, 0xFFFF0000

    orr w0,w0,w1
    mov w1,0x1624 // Range = 13bit 44100Hz Mono
    str w1,[x0,PWM_RNG1]
    str w1,[x0,PWM_RNG2]

    mov w1,PWM_USEF2 + PWM_PWEN2 + PWM_USEF1 + PWM_PWEN1 + PWM_CLRF1
    str w1,[x0,PWM_CTL]


.section .text.play_audio, "ax", %progbits
.balign 4
.globl play_audio;
.type play_audio, %function
play_audio:
    Loop:
        adr x1, _binary_src_audio_Interlude_bin_start // X1 = Sound Sample
        ldr w2, =_binary_src_audio_Interlude_bin_end
        and w2, w2, 0x0000FFFF // W2 = End Of Sound Sample
        ldr w3, =_binary_src_audio_Interlude_bin_end
        and w3, w3, 0xFFFF0000
        orr w2,w2,w3
        FIFO_Write:
            ldrh w3,[x1],2 // Write 2 Bytes To FIFO
            lsr w3,w3,3 // Convert 16bit To 13bit
            str w3,[x0,PWM_FIF1] // FIFO Address

            ldrh w3, [x1], 2
            lsr w3, w3, 3
            str w3, [x0, PWM_FIF1]
        FIFO_Wait:
            ldr w3,[x0,PWM_STA]
            tst w3,PWM_FULL1 // Test Bit 1 FIFO Full
            b.ne FIFO_Wait
        cmp w1,w2 // Check End Of Sound Sample
        b.ne FIFO_Write
    b Loop // Play Sample Again
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: Ensure that you have calling convention 100% right. In C, `void init_audio_jack_c()` does not mean a function taking no parameters, but a function taking _any_ parameters. Possibly it might end up in some curious calling convention, from the ABI's point of view. Needless to say, you have to make sure that you have the calling convention 100% correct (verify with disassembler). Apart from that, all the pointer arithmetic could be fine or it could hold hidden bugs, depending on the type of all those constants. Overall, the lack of `volatile` is fishy. Aren't you accessing hardware registers?

Comment: Yes they are hardware registers I will try using volatile. The defines are all unsigned ints.

Comment: I have added volatiles literally everywhere the addresses are even defined as volatile now however this has not changed the fact that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Lundin This is not the case on aarch64.  The lack of `void` in the parenthesis does not make a difference wrt calling convention.  Indeed, casting a `void (*)()` to `void (*)(void)` is legal as long as the `void (*)()` pointer actually points to a function defined not to take any arguments.

Comment: @fuz From my knowledge the above pieces of code are identical do you know whats going on?

Comment: @OliverStrong Nope.  I lack the willpower to dive through your assembly code and find out what tiny bit is different between the two.